# Laravel Model Closure - Soft Delete

Tags: laravel

I want to store the name of the user who creates, updates or soft deletes a model.  To accomplish this I added the following closures:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->created_by = session('userEmail');
        $model->updated_by = session('userEmail');

    });
    static::updating(function ($model) {
        $model->updated_by = session('userEmail');
    });
    static::deleting(function ($model) {
        $model->updated_by = session('userEmail');
        $model->deleted_by = session('userEmail');
    });
}
```

The `creating` and `updating` closures seem to work fine, but `deleting` never fires.  Is this because I am soft deleting instead of properly deleting? If so, how can I hook onto soft deleting?

This is how I am deleting in the model:

```
$table = Mytable::find($request->id);
$table->delete();
```

Comment: "seems" did you debug the deleting event with a dump or dd ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of SoftDeletes trait, it seems that an event named `trashed` is fired instead of the usual `deleting` event.

The SoftDeletes trait also introduces the following static event handler functions:

- `softDeleted()` which listens to the `trashed` event
- `restoring()` which listens to the `restoring` event
- `restored()` which listens to the `restored` event
- `forceDeleted()` which listens to the `forceDeleted` event

So basically, you have to use:

```php
static::softDeleted(function ($model) {
  $model->update([
    'updated_by' => session('userEmail'),
    'deleted_by' => session('userEmail'),
  ]);
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting `Call to undefined method App\Models\User::softDeleted()` and the same for `trashed`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the SoftDeletes trait on your model.